# Code_coverage sonarqube decimal scale

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, precision, sonarqube-ops

I am in situation where I want more precision than just 1 decimal place for code_coverage metric.

I saw that this is stored in sonar_qube in a table called metrics under decimal_scale.

If I set this to more than 1, when restarting sonarqube it gets reseted to default, that is 1.

Is there a way to change this? I want to have more precision?

Instead of 55.6 I would like something like 55.675

Comment: Why do you think changing the database this way is supported? You have to look at the sourcecode. See [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/measures/Metric.java) for a start.

Comment: I know that it is open source, but maybe a more useful tip? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coverage = (CT + CF + LC)/(2*B + EL)

```
 Where CT+CF=conditions_to_cover - uncovered_conditions 
  2*B=conditions_to_cover 
  LC=lines_to_cover - uncovered_lines 
  EL=lines_to_cover
```

So it can be computed out of existing metrics.